# Gstreamer tee branch with appsink slows down the whole pipeline, how to process buffer async?

Tags: computer-vision, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer, nvidia-deepstream

I have a deepstream pipeline which goes like this:

```
reading and processing video --> queue --> tee --> queue --> display
                                            |----> queue --> appsink
```

The appsink has a callback function attached to the "new-sample" bus messages to get a new sample from the buffer and process it. This operation inside the appsink is slow. I want everything running in the appsink to run async and to not slow down the display, is this possible?